# Implement Partial sorted query in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have to show records in such a way that some selected records should come first. After this, another records come in sorted manner from the same table.

For example, If I select state having stateID = 5 then the corresponding record should come first. after this another records should come in sorted manner.

For this, I tried union but it shows all in sorted.

```
select state from statemaster where stateid=5
union all
select state from statemaster
where not stateid =5
order by state
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one will use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx) to give you states with `stateid = 5` first, followed by the rest. Second sort-criteria is the `state`.

```
Select state
From statemaster
Order By
  Case When stateid = 5 Then 0 Else 1 End,
  state
```

Comment: +1. Didn't even know this was possible. Nice new trick to put into my bag.

Comment: I agree with you. this is a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful if you have more than 2 unions

```
select 1 as sort_id,  state from statemaster where stateid=5
union all
select 2 as sort_id, state from statemaster
where stateid between 1 and 4
union all
select 3 as sort_id, state from statemaster
where stateid > 5
order by sort_id, state
```